# Not able to access Oracle manager online. Port 5500 is closed

Tags: oracle, linux, centos, oracle-xe, oracle-18c

I am using Oracle 18c XE on CentOS 7. The database installed successfully but not able to bring it online to my hostname. what I did is:

Added port 5500 in firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=550/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

edited sqlplus as:

```
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(5500)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then trying to access as: https://linux.domain.com:5500/em

```
[root@linux ~]# lsof -i :5500
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tnslsnr 18295 oracle   16u  IPv6 864455      0t0  TCP *:fcp-addr-srvr1 (LISTEN)
```

When I check in ping.eu the port 5500 is closed

Best Regards

Comment: Is there a zero missing from the first `firewall-cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this part:

```
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(5500)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I configured 5500 on **HTTP** port but was trying to access it on **HTTPS**